# How to export a Tensorflow model with exogenous features

Tags: python, tensorflow, export, time-series

I try to export a Tensorflow model but I can not find the best way to add the exogenous feature to the `tf.contrib.timeseries.StructuralEnsembleRegressor.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn`.

I use the sample from the Tensorflow contrib: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/examples/known_anomaly.py and I just try to save the model.

```
# this is the exogenous column 
string_feature = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(
      column_name="is_changepoint", keys=["no", "yes"])

one_hot_feature = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_column(
      sparse_id_column=string_feature)

estimator = tf.contrib.timeseries.StructuralEnsembleRegressor(
      periodicities=12,    
      cycle_num_latent_values=3,
      num_features=1,
      exogenous_feature_columns=[one_hot_feature],
      exogenous_update_condition=
      lambda times, features: tf.equal(features["is_changepoint"], "yes"))

reader = tf.contrib.timeseries.CSVReader(
      csv_file_name,

      column_names=(tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.TIMES,
                    tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.VALUES,
                    "is_changepoint"),

      column_dtypes=(tf.int64, tf.float32, tf.string),

      skip_header_lines=1)

train_input_fn = tf.contrib.timeseries.RandomWindowInputFn(reader, batch_size=4, window_size=64)
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=train_steps)
evaluation_input_fn = tf.contrib.timeseries.WholeDatasetInputFn(reader)
evaluation = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=evaluation_input_fn, steps=1)

export_directory = tempfile.mkdtemp()

###################################################### 
# the exogenous column must be provided to the build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn. 
# But How ?
######################################################

input_receiver_fn = estimator.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn()
# -> error missing 'is_changepoint' key    

#input_receiver_fn = estimator.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn({'is_changepoint' : string_feature}) 
# -> cast exception

export_location = estimator.export_savedmodel(export_directory, input_receiver_fn)
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/timeseries/StructuralEnsembleRegressor), build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn **exogenous_features** parameter : *A dictionary mapping feature keys to exogenous features (either Numpy arrays or Tensors). Used to determine the shapes of placeholders for these features*.

So what is the best way to transform the *one_hot_column* or *sparse_column_with_keys* to a *Tensor* object ?

Answer (score 0):

As exogenous features could be either Numpy arrays or Tensors, I added those features as NumpyArrays like this:

```
input_receiver_fn = estimator.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(
      exogenous_features={"is_changepoint": [["yes", "no"]]})
```

At least the model is saved, but I am still not sure that is the right and best way to make it.